# How to get the scheduled time of Google Cloud Task by task name?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Is there any way I can get the time when the Cloud Task is scheduled to run using its task name?

I'm creating a task in a function using:

```js
const task = {
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    url,
    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  },
  scheduleTime: {
    seconds: 86400 
  }
}

const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })
return response.name;
```

It gives me a task name that looks like:

```
projects/.../queues/foo/tasks/987555410648792221
```

How can I get the time when this task will run at (epoch time) using the above task name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` is of type [ITask](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/tasks/latest/tasks/protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.itask) that has a [`scheduleTime`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/tasks/latest/tasks/protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.itask#_google_cloud_tasks_protos_google_cloud_tasks_v2_ITask_scheduleTime_member) property. Try:

```
console.log(`Task will trigger at ${response.scheduleTime?.seconds}`)
```

However, this is not necessary as you are supposed to pass the task trigger time as follows:

```
const task = {
  scheduleTime: {
    seconds: Date.now() + 86400 // Time at which task should trigger
  }
}
```

Just passing `86400` will run the tasks immediately.

---

If you know the task name, then you can use `getTask()` to fetch task information and read schedule time:

```
const [task] = await tasks.getTask({
  name: response.name, // <-- task name
});

console.log(`Task schedule time: ${task.scheduleTime?.seconds}`);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that, I need to get the time in other function.

Comment: @iDecode updated the answer. You should be able to fetch task information including any failed attempts as long as you have the task name

Comment: Actually I was using a `seconds: epochSeconds` variable in my code and when I asked the question, I just added random 86400 seconds, so yes, my code in the question won't work. But thanks `getTask` is what I was looking for!